# MySQL: How to create an alias from two different fields?

Tags: mysql

I have a query that is joining two tables. I would like to be able to create an alias that allows the value to default to a different field when the original field is null. Here is an example:

```
select
    Table1.Name, 
    Table2.Name, 
    (case when Table1.Name then Table2.Name else Table1.Name end) AS 'RealName'
from Table3
left join Table1 on Table1.ID = Table3.Table1_ID
left join Table2 on Table2.ID = Table3.Table2_ID
order by `RealName` asc
```

I am getting an "unknown column in field list" error when I try doing this.

**Update:** Turns out my unknown column error was due to something else. The [MySQL coalesce function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) worked great for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
...COALESCE(Table1.Name, Table2.Name) AS RealName...
```

Comment: @ain: Sure it does. [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

Answer (score 4):

Try this instead:

```
(case when Table1.Name IS NULL then Table2.Name else Table1.Name end) AS 'RealName'
```

**Edit**
And also in your Order by, change it to:

```
order by (case when Table1.Name IS NULL then Table2.Name else Table1.Name end) asc
```

**Edit 2**
As others have stated, you can also use `coalesce(Table1.Name, Table2.Name)` but I believe the error is still because you're referencing the aliased column in the `order by`. With either method, just put the code you're aliasing in the `order by` and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this once

```
select 
Table1.Name, 
Table2.Name,
(case when Table1.Name is null then Table2.Name else Table1.Name end) AS 'RealName' from Table3 left join Table1 on Table1.ID = Table3.Table1_ID left join Table2 on Table2.ID = Table3.Table2_ID order by `RealName` asc
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `COALESCE`:

```
Select * from (select
    Table1.Name, 
    Table2.Name, 
    coalesce(Table1.Name, Table2.Name) AS RealName
from Table3
left join Table1 on Table1.ID = Table3.Table1_ID
left join Table2 on Table2.ID = Table3.Table2_ID)
order by RealName asc
```

I don't know about MySQL, but other RDBMS won't let you use the RealName alias inside the "inner" query, therefore I've added the "outer" query.